# View counter: which is correct?

Tags: discussion, support

I noticed [one of my questions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/344909/defrosting-a-chicken-breast-and-the-laws-of-thermodynamics) has a different view count from the main [Physics.SE homepage](https://physics.stackexchange.com/)? Which view count is correct? The one displayed in the question itself or the one on the homepage?

For e.g. the question in question (nice!) says 2K views on the homepage and 1,544 views when you open the question!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I can tell it rounds to the nearest thousand when it gets that big.

1.5K rounds up to 2K, while the number in the question is the actual number.

Comment: Yeah, pretty much. Note that (i) the precise view counter is available as a tooltip from the front page, (ii) plenty of other numbers are also rounded off in that view, such as e.g. high rep numbers and time-since-last-activity markers, and (iii) those also have tooltips with the precise number.